# Rsyslog задать имя для переменной hostname

Tags: rsyslog

Когда лог прилетает в таком виде, проблем нет! Переменная `hostname` определяется верно:

```
*Apr  1 14:27:19 IS-01-SW02 %%01SHELL/5/CMDRECORD(s)[4023]: Recorded command information. (Task=TICK, Ip=**, VpnName=...)*
```

Но есть устройства, в которых я не могу отключить параметр **without-timezone**, и логи с таких устройств прилетают с указанием часового пояса, например:

```
*Apr 29 2023 15:55:50+04:00 FS-02-SW01 %%01LLDP/4/hwLldpInterfaceRemTablesCh....*
```

В таких случаях переменная `hostname` вычисляется неверно (`apr`), видимо, сбивает +04:00.

Как объяснить сервису rsyslog, что он должен считывать переменную со значением `hostname` после указания часового пояса?

Пока условием `if` я ищу значения +04:00 в `msg`, чтобы просто отфильтровать такие сообщения, но все они льются в один файл с именем `apr`:(